# XSLT-style mini transformation in Xquery?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

At the moment in Xquery 3.1 (in eXist 4.7)  I receive XML fragments that look like the following (from eXist's Lucene full text search):

```
let $text :=

 <tei:text>
   <front>
     <tei:div>
        <tei:listBibl>
            <tei:bibl>There is some</tei:bibl>
            <tei:bibl>text in certain elements</tei:bibl>
        </tei:listBibl>
     </tei:div>
     <tei:div>
        <tei:listBibl>
            <tei:bibl>which are subject <exist:match>to</exist:match> a Lucene search</tei:bibl>
            <tei:bibl></tei:bibl>
        <tei:listBibl>
     </tei:div>
   <tei:front>
   <tei:body>
     <tei:p>and often produces</tei:p>
     <tei:p>a hit.</tei:p>
   <tei:body>
 <tei:text>
```

Currently I have Xquery send this fragment to an XSLT stylesheet in order to transform it into HTML like this:

```
<td>...elements which are subject <span class="search-hit">to</span> a Lucene search and often p...
```

Where the stylesheet's job is to return 30 characters of text before and after `<exist:match/>` and put the content of `<exist:match/>` into a span. There is only one `<exist:match/>` per transformation.

This all works fine. However, it's occurred to me that it is a very small job with effectively a single transformation of only one element, the rest being a sort of string-join. I therefore wonder if this can't be done efficiently in Xquery.

In trying to do this, I'm can't seem to find a way to handle the string content up to the `<exist:match/>` and then the string content after `<exist:match/>`. My idea is, in pseudo code, to output a result like:

```
let $textbefore := some function to get the text before <exist:match/>
let $textafter := some function to get text before <exist:match/>
return <td>...{$textbefore} 
        <span class="search-hit">
          {$text//exist:match/text()}
        </span> {$textafter}...</td>
```

Is this even worth doing in Xquery vs the current Xquery -> XSLT pipeline I have?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the XSLT you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done as

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare namespace tei = "http://example.com/tei";
declare namespace exist = "http://example.com/exist";

declare option output:method 'html';

let $text :=

 <tei:text>
   <tei:front>
     <tei:div>
        <tei:listBibl>
            <tei:bibl>There is some</tei:bibl>
            <tei:bibl>text in certain elements</tei:bibl>
        </tei:listBibl>
     </tei:div>
     <tei:div>
        <tei:listBibl>
            <tei:bibl>which are subject <exist:match>to</exist:match> a Lucene search</tei:bibl>
            <tei:bibl></tei:bibl>
        </tei:listBibl>
     </tei:div>
   </tei:front>
   <tei:body>
     <tei:p>and often produces</tei:p>
     <tei:p>a hit.</tei:p>
   </tei:body>
 </tei:text> 
 , 
 $match := $text//exist:match,
 $text-before-all := normalize-space(string-join($match/preceding::text(), ' ')),
 $text-before := substring($text-before-all, string-length($text-before-all) - 30),
 $text-after := substring(normalize-space(string-join($match/following::text(), ' ')), 1, 30)
return 
 <td>...{$text-before} 
        <span class="search-hit">
          {$match/text()}
        </span> {$text-after}...</td>
```

which is not really much of a query in XQuery either but just some XPath selection plus some possibly expensive string joining and extraction on the preceding and following axis.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll let you know if it's expensive as I am dealing with a large document set (for TEI  i.e. 13000+).

Comment: It is more quite expensive - double the time on each of three different sizes of datasets. I guess this is why XML developers talk about pipelines with mixed approaches. Worth a try! Thanks as always.

Comment: I am not sure what you did in XSLT, the above is obviously just trying to collect all preceding and following text and then taking the substring, there might be more efficient ways to select only the few text nodes needed to have the 30 or whatever characters you want to display, but as the structure seems to have the text at various levels in various elements I couldn't find a clear and easy way to select only 30 characters. Perhaps someone else comes up with a better expression, my attempt at least served to discover a bug in Saxon 9.9 https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4309.

Comment: Indeed and the entire process is determined by eXist's Lucene implementation which requires passing it the fragments it has already indexed. The search engine won't work on temporary XML created in memory (i.e. get all the text, then find the match). Frankly the XSLT transformations are really fast, I was just thinking about refactoring old code for a new project...

Comment: I would be very very surprised if doing this in XSLT using eXist-db was faster than doing it in XQuery. If your documents are stored in the database, eXist-db can take advantage of various structural indexes. Either way, calling Saxon from eXist-db has a performance penalty as we have to translate DOM models.

I suspect something is wrong with the performance measuring here. If you absolutely believe that the XSLT is faster through eXist-db, feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/exist-db/exist/issues